# jquery widget access options outside the widget

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

How do I access the widget options outside the widget, not inside the widget?  I can call functions, but I need to check some options.

Comment: what do you want? do you have an example?

Answer (score 0):

you can define a public getter method that will return the options object..

widget definition:

```
    $(function(){
        $.widget("namespace.mywidget", {
        options:{member1:"ab",
                 member2: "cd"},
        _create:function() {},
        // here is the getter..
        getOptions:function(){
          return this.options;
       }
     });
   });
```

And the script goes like this..

```
    var x1=$("#div1").mywidget();  //initialize the widget..
    var opts=x1.mywidget("getOptions"); //call getOptions method.
```

the variable opts will hold the options object.
Iterate over opts to check the values..

--Happy Programming..